# FluentMigrator - Execute resource file/script

Tags: c#, sql, dll, fluent-migrator

I try migrate one of my databases with FluentMigrator.
One of the migrations tries to execute a script.
I thought: "I only want to send the DLL to my colleagues"
So I packed the SQL-Script into the DLL as a resource-file and now try to access it, but it seems like the Script is not found.

**Migration**

```
[Migration(201506021451)]
public class M116_Init_RoleManagement : ForwardOnlyMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Table("Role")
              .WithIdColumn()
              .WithColumn("Name").AsString().NotNullable();

        Insert.IntoTable("Role").Row(new { Name = "Administrator" });
        Insert.IntoTable("Role").Row(new { Name = "Manager" });
        Insert.IntoTable("Role").Row(new { Name = "SalesManager" });
        Insert.IntoTable("Role").Row(new { Name = "Employee" });

        Create.Table("EmployeeRole")
              .WithIdColumn()
              .WithColumn("EmployeeId").AsInt64().NotNullable()
              .WithColumn("RoleId").AsInt64().NotNullable();
        Execute.Script(Hsk.Migrations.Properties.Resources._2015021451_CreateSalesManagerRoles);
    }
}
```

**Resource File**
[image: ResourceFile]

**Projectstructure**

[image: ProjectExplorer]

**Error**

> 201506021451: M116_Init_RoleManagement migrating =========================
> Beginning Transaction
>
> Rolling back transaction
>
> Illegal Sign in Path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer is pretty obvious:
Accessing the resource-file via  `Hsk.Migrations.Properties.Resources._2015021451_CreateSalesManagerRoles`
returns the content of and not the path to the file.

So the call should look like

```
[Migration(201506021451)]
public class M116_Init_RoleManagement : ForwardOnlyMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        .
        .
        . 
        Execute.Sql(Hsk.Migrations.Properties.Resources._2015021451_CreateSalesManagerRoles);
    }
}
```